# Bootstrap: show space between spans

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

I have been using bootstrap for my project for responsive fluid layout and I'm happy with this interface.

There are 12 spans i use for designing blocks in a row.
Here is bootstrap's for a row :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <img src="block.png">
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <p><!---some text---></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will show these spans in row and looks good on full width screen.

**Problem**

I don't have any problem in full screen view but when i do narrow to screen one of the block goes to next line and there is not space between these two blocks.

It happens like this-

**Full screen layout**

[image]

**Narrow screen**
[image]

How do i get space b/w span lines?

Comment: add bootstrap-responsive.css

Answer (score 1):

Add a logo class to your logo

```
<img src="URL" alt="ALT" class="logo"/>
```

Then use Sieu Phan's answer with the `margin-bottom`:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .logo
    {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the media query, you can add styles based on the screen size, so I don't know at what width your layout changes but for this example I'm going to use 700px, once the screen's width gets to 700px, the class span8 gets the style `margin-top: (your desired margin)px;` That's how I did my styling in bootstrap. This should allow you to have the extra space above span8, once your responsiveness kicks in.

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .span8
    {
        margin-top: (x)px;
    }
}
```

Comment: i've given it a try but that margin happens when inline also.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle with your css?